# (almost) no file in the build of next project initialised with

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hy,
everytime  I init a nextJs project with

```
 npx create-next-app
```

when I do `npm run build`

I endup with only 2 file in the .next dir:

```
package.json
routes-manifest.json
```

I don't have this issue when I use cloned nextjs project.

Any idea why I don't have builded file?